# Inputs on Samsung CCFL Inverter

Tags: inverter, ccfl

I am trying to use the backlight from a Samsung laptop for a light box but have NO idea what the input connections are. I've found some Datasheets for other models but not the right one. LTN141XB-L01

Most other inverters seem to have 6 wires but this connector has 12 and is rather complicated. I understand there are several 12v Inputs, grounds and an on/off 5v input but which wires they are is a complete mystery.

[image]

Comment: A link to a (quality) picture or two of the control board would probably help (we can add it into your question for you) If it's anything like the couple I've seen, it's probably possible to bypass some of the circuitry and power the inverter IC directly.

Comment: Actually no pics I'm afraid, I'm new and it says I need 10 reputation to submit images. Not sure what to do here?

Comment: Put them on a pic sharing site and link to them, we'll add them in for you.

Comment: Ok, here goes.....   http://www.flickr.com/photos/medaveo/

Comment: LTN141XB-L01 is not the inverter part number. It is the lcd screen's part number. Additionally, you might want to take off the klaxon tape (the orange stuff) and note down the chips on the inverter. You might have to trace and use a continuity option on a multimeter.

Comment: Yes that is The Samsung screen part number. (hence the Data sheet I was looking for with inverter connection table) I see your point with the multimeter. Do you mean trace back the tracks to obtain input voltages etc on these chips?

Comment: @Dave - thanks for the pic. As Passerby says, a couple of closer shots with the tape taken off and IC numbers visible would be great. If you don't have a good enough macro lens, a 10x loupe (or magnifying glass) can be used with a phone camera to achieve suprisingly good results.

Comment: Ok, better pics are ready...Thanks... http://www.flickr.com/photos/medaveo/

Comment: kapton tape : klaxon is a bit noisier :-p

Comment: Hehe... i thought it was Kapton! :)

Comment: Ok so I've buzzed out what I can from IC Datasheets and found pins 5, 8 & 11 seem to connect to Vcc and ground in many cases. Is this how it should be? Could I connect 12Vdc to 5, 8 & 11 and use chassis for ground as a start?

Comment: Oh dear..... :(